Can we use same instance of ThreadPoolTaskExecutor for two consecutive steps
recently i have been using same threadpool taskexecutor instance for two consecutive steps in batch job, below is the configuration for these beans, i want to know is it advisable to use same pool for multiple steps. How will it impact the performance and what are the downside of this configuration
    <bean id="taskExecutorThreadPool" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
            <property name="corePoolSize" value="24"/>
            <property name="maxPoolSize" value="30"/>
            <property name="queueCapacity" value="50"/>
    </bean>

<batch:step id="localitySale" next="localityRent">
            <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="jobRepository-transactionManager" task-executor="taskExecutorThreadPool" throttle-limit="30">
                <batch:chunk reader="readerlocalitySrpSeoPageLinks" processor="processorlocalitySrpSeoPageLinks"
                    writer="writerlocalitySrpPageLinks" commit-interval="1000">
                </batch:chunk>
                <batch:listeners>
                    <batch:listener ref="localitySrpListener" />
                </batch:listeners>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
        <batch:step id="localityRent" >
            <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="jobRepository-transactionManager" task-executor="taskExecutorThreadPool" throttle-limit="30">
                <batch:chunk reader="readerlocalitySrpSeoPageLinks" processor="processorlocalitySrpSeoPageLinks"
                    writer="writerlocalitySrpPageLinks" commit-interval="1000">
                </batch:chunk>
                <batch:listeners>
                    <batch:listener ref="localitySrpListener" />
                </batch:listeners>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>

